# Azure function prints out the http error message

Tags: azure

I have been trying to execute an azure function. The function does some calculation and returns a json response. If I just print out the json, it gets printed, but the log also contain the below error statement:

```
2020-06-05T05:03:35.256 [Error] Executed 'Functions.curvefitting' (Failed, Id=8b47fa39-746e-4153-9451-d18bb79ed4cd)

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest'.
```

I have coded my `main` function as:

```py
import azure.functions as af

def main(myblob: af.InputStream) -> str:
json_response = <some calculatios>
return json_response
```

And here's my `function.json` file:

```js
{
  "scriptFile": "xyz.py",
  "entryPoint": "main",
  "bindings":[
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "myblob",
      "path": "xyz.xlsx",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "methods":[
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. I am new to azure functions.

Comment: The error: it cannot cast a `System.Byte[]` to a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest`. Are you mixing HttpTrigger and BlobTrigger? Could you show us your `function.json`? Also, please refer to [Azure Functions Python developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python)

Comment: Hi rickvdbosch,   my function.json file is                                                                                {
 "scriptFile": "xyz.py",
 "entryPoint": "main",
 "bindings": [
 {
 "authLevel": "function",
 "type": "blobTrigger",
 "direction": "in",
 "name": "myblob",
 "path": "xyz.xlsx",
 "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
 "methods": [
 "get",
 "post"
 ]
 },
 {
 "type": "http",
 "direction": "out",
 "name": "$return"
 }
 ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Json file it looks like you *started out* with an HttpTriggered function, but you changed it to a BlobTriggered function. Your input binding defines a `blobTrigger`, but there's also `methods` there (which are HTTP methods) and the output binding is an HTTP binding.

Most important question is: what are you trying to achieve? If this should be an HttpTriggered function that uses a Blob as input, define an HttpTrigger and an input binding for the blob.

This would be an example of an HttpTriggered Function with an *input* Blob binding:

```js
{
  "scriptFile": "xyz.py",
  "entryPoint": "main",
  "bindings":[
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "path": "xyz.xlsx",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your main entry point would look something like

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, myblob: func.InputStream) -> func.HttpResponse:
```

For more information and examples, see [Azure Blob storage input binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python) and [Azure Functions HTTP trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited the function.json file as mentioned. I noticed that my python function does correct calculations, but fail while giving output. The return statement of my python file is just:       return <json object>                                                                                                                             I modified this to                                                                                                               return func.HttpResponse(json_object, mimetype = "application/json"), but the error still persists. Pls help

Comment: my bad. I mentioned two triggers: httpTrigger and blobTrigger in a single function.json file. The code that you mentioned in your response works now. Thanks. You are of great help